# Is there a way to refactor multiple similar PHP ternaries?

Tags: php

I had some code that felt like had a lot of repetition in it.  I got it down to the following chunk, but I still see a handful of things being repeated and it feels like there should be a cleaner way to write it.  Is there anything more that can be done or is this it?

```
$w1 = ($fin[57] > $fin[60]) ? $tc[57] : $tc[60];
$l1 = ($fin[57] > $fin[60]) ? $tc[60] : $tc[57];
$w2 = ($fin[58] > $fin[59]) ? $tc[58] : $tc[59];
$l2 = ($fin[58] > $fin[59]) ? $tc[59] : $tc[58];
```

What I'd really like is if there was a way to get the ternary to return an array of the true and false values.  Something like this fictitious code:

```
list($w1, $l1) = (array) ($fin[57] > $fin[60]) ? $tc[57] : $tc[60];
list($w2, $l2) = (array) ($fin[58] > $fin[59]) ? $tc[58] : $tc[59];
```

Comment: Some more context would help here. Can we see the bigger picture this algorithm is supposed to solve? Perhaps an entirely different approach could make those lines obsolete entirely.

Comment: @deceze - in this `$fin` represents the final score for game side id #57, etc.   `$tc` represents an id a team playing that side (think of "side" as "home" or "away").  So there's a game on the schedule where #57 plays #60.  The team who gets the #57 spot is assigned with `$tc[57]`. The team id of the winner of that game gets assigned to the `$w1` variable.  Not sure if that explanation helps or makes it more confusing.  Eventually the $w1 team will go on to game side id #61.  But that's probably not important for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list` to make it a little better:

```
$order = function ($i1, $i2) use ($fin, $tc) {
    $r = [$tc[$i1], $tc[$i2]];
    if ($fin[$i2] > $fin[$i1]) $r = array_reverse($r);
    return $r;
};
list($w1, $l1) = $order(57, 60);
list($w2, $l2) = $order(58, 59);
```

Comment: What if those two variables aren’t `global`…?

Comment: @deceze It was meant to show the idea but that should be fixed now.

Comment: Hm, that idea may be good if I had a lot of instances, but I only have two comparisons to make.  I just edited my question to show pseudocode of the sort of answer I was hoping for.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I don't think there’s a shorter way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the shortest you could do without a function is this, but there's still a quite a bit of repetition:

```
[$w1, $l1] = $fin[57] > $fin[60] ? [$tc[57], $tc[60]] : [$tc[60], $tc[57]];
```

You could also do a very small function using PHP 7.4's short closures, if you're using that (the PHP < 7.4 version is closer to the other answer):

```
$wlValues = fn($i, $j) => $fin[$i] > $fin[$j] ? [$tc[$i], $tc[$j]] : [$tc[$j], $tc[$i]];
```

Usage:

```
[$w1, $l1] = $wlValues(57, 60);
```